# How to remove update alerts from wagtail dashboard page

Tags: wagtail

I would like to disable the wagtail update alert from the the dashboard. I'm concerned it alarms my clients. I do appreciate the reminder, but there is no way to dismiss it. I guessing the only course of action at this point is to go into the wagtail admin template and simply comment out the applicable code?

Answer (score 7):

There is the [`WAGTAIL_ENABLE_UPDATE_CHECK`](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.8/advanced_topics/settings.html#wagtail-update-notifications) setting in Wagtail.

To disable update alerts you need to add the following line to your settings file:

```
WAGTAIL_ENABLE_UPDATE_CHECK = False
```